# Unchangable classes under single interface

Tags: java

Have generated classes (stubs) like:

```
class A {
    int getA() {...}
    int getB() {...}
    int getC() {...}
}

class B {
    int getA() {...}
    int getB() {...}
    int getD() {...}
}
```

here is no possibility to change this classes.
I want to get possibility like this classes implementing single interface with common methods:

```
interface SimpleAB {
     int getA();
     int getB();
}
```

Dont want to use reflection API. 
Someone have idea hot to do this in elegant way?

Comment: Seems like X-Y problem. What indeed you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Naturally. Want to have, for example, single validation method for A and B class.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a wrapper for each class. If Escape Analysis kicks in it might not even create a new object.

```
interface SimpleAB {
    int getA();
    int getB();

    static SimpleAB wrap(A a) { return new SimpleAB() { /* delegate */ }; }
    static SimpleAB wrap(B b) { return new SimpleAB() { /* delegate */ }; }
}
```

This way you can wrap an `A` or `B` and then treat them as the same.

Comment: Not bad ) thank for response. Functional interfaces?

Comment: @PashaDoro I'd recommend you take a look at Kotlin, it can do this a lot more convenient and compiles to java bytecode. If your interested, take a look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

Comment: You can create a generic `wrap` factory method: `static <T> SimpleAB wrap(T ab, Function<T, Integer> getA, Function<T, Integer> getB) { return new SimpleAB() { int getA() { return getA.apply(ab); } int getB() { return getB.apply(ab); } }` - call with `SimpleAB fromA = wrap(a, A::getA, A::getB)`.